# Ruby on rails gem tinymce-rails not including needed js files on hosted environment

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I installed tinymce-rails gem, and included the coffeescript include so that the wysiwyg editor appears on a particular view. I added it to assets/javascripts/application.js file as shown below;

```
//= require tinymce-jquery
```

This works great when running on webrick on local machine. It worked fine in the development environment, and after tweaking a couple of variables in the production.rb file it started working locally as well in production environment.

However once I deploy to my webhost (webbynode) and open the view that the editor is supposed to appear in, the javascript for tinymce does not get included. I played a bit with some of the variables in the environment/production.rb file which seemed to make a difference locally, but it did not make a difference in the hosted environment. Any ideas on this?